# Green residues are present on all my prints, and the adhesion is pretty bad

Tags: print-quality, troubleshooting, print-material

It has been three weeks since I first tried to solve this problem. [Here's](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PlbR6.jpg) the video. I cleaned the hotend yesterday, as it was fully clogged and full of plastic.

My heatsink seems to be attached good. I didn't touch it even once since I bought my Ender 3 Pro.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add more information and some relevant photos, don’t link to external content. Furthermore, the video doesn’t add anything to your question. As it stands now it will most probably be closed by the community.

Comment: When cleaning the nozzle/block did the top of the heater block have filament build up? something like this? [Leeky heat break](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8BpPw.jpg) If yes, then this should be of help to you: [What causes leaking between the heat break and the heat block?](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/11316/what-causes-leaking-between-the-heat-break-and-the-heat-block)

Comment: My heatsink seems to be attached good. I didn't touch it even once since I bought my ender 3 pro

Comment: If you put the video on YouTube (rather than imgur) then it can be embedded into your question. However, a photo of the issue would be useful as well as some additional textual information. Clearly you are frustrated with the issue, but the more information that you can provide the more likely that someone will be able to help you (as the less likely that it will be closed). Also, please add additional information in your question and **not** in the comments (I have added your comment to your question for you, this time).